# One liner to enable some SCLs and a python virtual environment?

Tags: python, scl

I'm writing a python 3.4 app on a centos box. Normally, when I have to reset my tmux session, such as after a reboot I do the following:

```
[zippy@localhost ~]$ scl enable rh-python34 httpd24 bash
[zippy@localhost ~]$ source python34/bin/activate
(python34)[zippy@localhost ~]$
```

I could do it in one command, but I lose my prompt, and therefore presumably other stuff.

```
[zippy@localhost ~]$ scl enable rh-python34 httpd24 "source ../python34/bin/activate && bash"
(python34)
```

I'm actually not sure why I can't just enter the virtual environment without enabling scl, but it still try to execute the default python instead of the scl one that I created the virtual environment with.

Answer (score -1):

```
scl enable rh-python34 httpd24 -- bash --rcfile <(echo '. ~/python34/bin/activate')
```